# create a dataframe from json response with columns (all_urls, description, name, price)

Tags: python-3.x

The dictionary data given below I want to get dataframe of columns names "all_urls", "description", "name", "price".

```
{
     "all_urls":["http://url1.com","http://url2.com", "http://url3.com"],
     "known":[{"description":"Decription here",
               "name":"Product nam",
                "price":20,
                "url":"http://url1.com"},
              {"description":"Decription here",
               "name":"Product name",
               "price":50,       
               "url":"http://url2.com"}
             ]}
}

{
    "all_urls":["http://url21.com","http://url22.com", "http://url23.com"],
     'known': []

}
```

Comment: Do you want a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a new dict with only the values you need and then use [pandas.DataFrame.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) method for conversion.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = { 
     "all_urls":["http://url1.com","http://url2.com", "http://url3.com"],
     "known":[{"description":"Decription here",
               "name":"Product nam",
                "price":20,
                "url":"http://url1.com"},
              {"description":"Decription here",
               "name":"Product name",
               "price":50,    
               "url":"http://url2.com"}
             ]}


parsed_data = { "all_urls":data["all_urls"],
                "description":[i["description"] for i in data["known"]],
                "name":[i["name"] for i in data["known"]],
                "price":[i["price"] for i in data["known"]] }

data_as_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(parsed_data,orient="index")

print(data_as_df)
```

**Output**

```
                           0                1                2
all_urls     http://url1.com  http://url2.com  http://url3.com
description  Decription here  Decription here             None
name             Product nam     Product name             None
price                     20               50             None
```

For the parsing I used list comprehension for simplification.
I hope it is in the format you want it.